# How to start camera intent with predefined dimensions?

Tags: android, crop, android-camera-intent

I don't want user to crop the image after the capture, but instead I want to open a cropped camera. The activity will take ImageView's dimensions and start camera activity with those dimensions.

onClick:

```
int targetWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int targetHeight = imageView.getHeight();

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 15);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 15);
intent.putExtra("outputX", targetWidth);
intent.putExtra("outputY", targetHeight);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA_ID);
```

Is such a thing possible with code like this?

Answer (score 0):

> instead I want to open a cropped camera.

You will need to write your own camera code from scratch, using `android.hardware.Camera` and/or the `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes.

With respect to the code in your question:

- [None of those extras are documented or supported for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) (or anything else in the Android SDK, for that matter)
- Of the thousands of camera apps that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` might start across the world's ~2 billion Android devices, few if any will have this feature in general, let alone available via some public API